# Create a vector that contains the topic value for the document based on highest gamma value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one data frame which contain 3 variable (`document`, `topic` and `gamma`)

```
document    topic   gamma
1            1      0.932581726
1            2      0.015250915
1            3      0.009929329
2            1      0.032864538
2            2      0.012939786
2            3      0.13281681
```

I want to create one vector contain the topic value for the document based on   highest gamma value. For which topic gamma value is high , document is belong to that topic.

I have tried some code but not sure is this the correct way to get it.

```
a2<-function(x){
  i=1
while(i< 110)
  for(j in 1:7)
    x= max(ap_documents$gamma)
  return(j)
  }
a3<-sapply(ap_documents,a2)
```

Comment: You want the max gamma values for each topic?

Comment: no i want the topic value in the vector based on the highest gamma value.

Comment: Try `df[as.logical(ave(df$gamma,df$document,FUN=function(x) x==max(x))),]`. Many other solutions are possible with `data.table` and `dplyr` packages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(document) %>%
  filter(gamma == max(gamma))
#output
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups: document [2]
  document topic gamma
     <int> <int> <dbl>
1        1     1 0.933
2        2     3 0.133
```

in base R you can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(gamma ~ document, max, data = df)
#output
  document     gamma
1        1 0.9325817
2        2 0.1328168
```

if you would like to keep the topic column you can merge it back:

```
merge(aggregate(gamma ~ document, max, data = df), df)
#output
  document     gamma topic
1        1 0.9325817     1
2        2 0.1328168     3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although the other solutions work fine, I'd like to mention the `top_n`-function in `dplyr`, which was build to solve similar tasks:

```
library(dplyr)

my_df %>% 
  group_by(document) %>% 
  top_n(1, topic)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   document [2]
#   document topic   gamma
#      <int> <int>   <dbl>
# 1        1     3 0.00993
# 2        2     3 0.133
```

Another simple base R solution is also:

```
my_df <- my_df[order(my_df$topic, decreasing = TRUE), ]
my_df[!duplicated(my_df$document), ]

#   document topic       gamma
# 3        1     3 0.009929329
# 6        2     3 0.132816810
```

**Data**

```
my_df <- structure(list(document = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                        topic = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
                        gamma = c(0.932581726, 0.015250915, 0.009929329, 
                                  0.032864538, 0.012939786, 0.13281681)), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want you can use `dplyr` to accomplish it.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>% 
    group_by(topic) %>% 
    slice(topic_gamma = which.max(gamma))

result
## A tibble: 2 x 3
## Groups:   document [2]
#  document topic gamma
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1       1.    1. 0.933
#2       2.    3. 0.133
```